# How do I error handling in Invoke-WebRequest?

Tags: powershell

2022-12-01: проблема ЧАСТИЧНО решена к версии 7.3.

The documentation recommends «Try-Catch». The problems are as follows.
0. Update: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16145

1. The «Catch [System.Net.WebException]» option has never worked for me, «Catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException]» has always been activated. It is activated when divided by zero, for example. Can they be separated into different groups?
2. For different errors, the method and property sets of the automatic variable «$_ » in the «Catch»-block are different. Accessing the method BEFORE ERROR UNDERSTANDING may cause a new error. So far, I see ONLY ONE constant parameter: «$_.Exception.HResult». Is it really the ONLY one? There is not a word in the documentation about this.
3. At the break of the connection during the downloading process (for example, the router rebooted) no error occurs at all, the next statement in the «Try»-block is executed and «$Error.Count» is not increased, and the file on the disk remains PARTIALLY downloaded (although with some types of content it may be absent, it seems). Is it normal?
   The third-party utility «cURL» at break of connection return errors with NON-ZERO codes 18 and 28 (perhaps, and others, I don't remember for sure). In PowerShell is this possible?
   Notabene: to reboot the router or disconnect the cable you must to use your hands, not sample of my code.
4. Removed.
5. The part of my program written in the language that I know (not English).

```
$Error.Count  
Try {  
      # Для самых НЕвнимательных ПОВТОРЯЮ И ПОДЧЁРКИВАЮ, что  
      #     меня интересуют ошибки «Invoke-WebRequest»,  
      #     а НЕ ДЕЛЕНИЯ.  Как их отделить друг от друга?  
      #     Именно об этом я написал в исходном вопросе!  
      <# 1/0 # Для проверки этого случая раскомментируйте вручную. #>  
      Invoke-WebRequest -URI СсылкаНаБольшойФайл -ErrorAction Stop  
      $Error.Count  
} Catch [System.Net.WebException] { # In THIS order!  
      "Эта секция не выполняется НИКОГДА."  
} Catch [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException] {  
      "Эта секция выполняется ВСЕГДА при ошибках 1/0 and «IWR»."  
      "Управление попадает сюда при ЛЮБЫХ ошибках из моего примера,"  
      "     КАК арифметических, ТАК и сетевых.  Всё в одну кучу."  
      # Для самых НЕвнимательных ПОВТОРЯЮ И ПОДЧЁРКИВАЮ, что  
      #     меня интересуют ошибки «Invoke-WebRequest»,  
      #     а НЕ ДЕЛЕНИЯ.  Как их отделить друг от друга?  
      #     Именно об этом я написал в исходном вопросе!  
      # Следующая строка может вызвать ошибку,  
      #     потому что такого метода/свойства просто нет.  
      #     А может выполниться БЕЗ прерывания.  Как повезёт.  
      $_.Exception.InnerException.ErrorCode  
      "В документации НИ слова о том,"
      "    какие элементы (методы/свойства) присутствуют ВСЕГДА."  
} Catch [System.SystemException] { # In THIS order!  
      "Эта секция не выполняется НИКОГДА."  
} Catch { # In THIS order!  
      "Эта секция не выполняется НИКОГДА."  
}
```

Comment: You need to share a sample of the code you are working.

Comment: Sorry, at this place I can not make the new line («comments cannot be multi-line»©?!), and 600 symbols only.  What can I to share my code?  I am on this site for the first time.

Comment: @КоваленкоАнатолийВикторович, use the [edit] button and add your code directly into your question.

Comment: Well, did it get any easier? A day passed, and no shifts. Looks like I am just not going to use this faulty comandlet.

Comment: Raging against volunteers on the internet isn't going to help you get answers. Nobody is obliged to answer questions. Once you have built up reputation, you can put [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on questions to have more attention drawn to them.

Comment: Why would you expect `catch [System.Net.WebException]` to catch division by zero? You'll want `catch [System.DivideByZeroException]`

Comment: I am trying to solve my technical problem using links from the official website of «PowerShell». I do not obliged to admire those from whom there is no benefit. Error handling («Try-Catch») is an most essential part of any programming language. The fact that no one in this site understands it is better than any words about the qualification of «volunteers».

Comment: To «Mathias R. Jessen» about division by zero.  
Please, READ more carefully. I do not expect, I am observing. My question concerns Internet requests by means of «IWR», not division.  I am trying to figure out how to focus on «IWR» errors, separate them from others. The fact that the corresponding section «Catch» gets division errors, it annoys myself. On the contrary, I ask how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

So I've run your code and have observed the following:

- PowerShell 5.1 emits a WebException on failure.
- PowerShell 7 emits a System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException, if you catch that it would separate the web exceptions from your hypothetical divide by zero.

If the inner exceptions of your HttpRequestException is a SocketException then you can use the ErrorCode field to get the underlying Windows Sockets error:

```
try{
  $res = Invoke-WebRequest -URI 'https://notexist.example.com/' -ErrorAction Stop
}catch[System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException]{
  $_.exception.innerexception.errorcode
}

11001
```

A list of the possible codes is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2

However at this point you've got to ask yourself are you really going to take a different action in your code for a DNS failure, a connection failure, connection refused, and every other possible option on that list?

As for your final point, when I unplug the network cable PowerShell 7 just hangs indefinitely, that could be this open bug: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12249

Comment: Thank you.  I observed errors with numbers 11001, 10013, 10053, 10060.  But I somehow managed to interrupt the hang at the break of Internet connection.  Now I can not repeat this.

Comment: The bug №12249 is not corrected for the second year. This means that the comandlet «Invoke-WebRequest» is simply unsuitable for work. The third-party program cURL handles such situations perfectly.  I shall to use it.

Comment: I do not know what version 5 is. I started working with PowerShell when version 6 was current.